# Umarshalling nested arrays with MOXy

Tags: java, json, jaxb, moxy

I'm using JAXB and MOXy to unmarshal structure like

```
"coordinates": [
    [
        [
            -5.9105761,
            54.6850694
        ],
        [
            -5.6877263,
             54.6850694
        ]
    ]
]
```

Usually, when I'm facing json arrays, I just use code like

```
Integer[] coordinate;
@XmlElement(name = "coordinate")
public Integer[] getCoordinate(){
    return coordinate;
}
public void setCoordinate...
```

and it works. So, for that structure I wanted to use similar code

```
Float[][][] coordinates;
@XmlElement(name = "coordinates")
public Float[][][] getCoordinates(){...
```

But during unmarshalling MOXy throws NPE. Can't you tell me, what's wrong with that approach?
Regards, Mikhail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently MOXy does not support multi-dimensional JSON arrays.  You can use the following enhancement request to track this feature:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/389815

Comment: too bad! @BlaiseDoughan, is there any chance we will get this feature? The ticket seems pretty quiet for some time now.